# ruby で ordered hash 的なことがやりたい

Tags: ruby, アルゴリズム, データ構造

ruby で、木構造で実装される Map データ構造が扱いたくなりました。以下の条件を満たすクラスはありますか？ないし、実装したライブラリなどはありますか？

- `h.set(key, value)` で値を store でき、 `h.get(key)` にてそれを取得できる。それらは O(log(N)) 以下で実行できる
- `h.find_sup(key)` にて、 `key` よりも大きな最小のキーと、それに対応する値のペアを取得できる。それが O(log(N)) で実行できる。

Answer (score 2):

GemsのRBTreeを試してみてください。
https://rubygems.org/gems/rbtree/versions/0.4.2

RBTreeのDocumentationはリンク先ページの右側から見ることができます。